# iphone gets dimmer occasionally

Tags: iphone, display

I have auto brightness turned off, and I still notice sometimes my iphone will get dimmer randomly. When it gets dimmer, I check the brightness and it's on max brightness, so I'm not sure what's going on. Could someone advise?

I am using iphone 12 pro on iOS 13.1 though this problem occured in the past on older iOS versions. The use is indoor and there's seemingly no lighting change in my environment

Comment: Is the weather hot where you are? Are you in the sun?

Comment: Which iPhone, what version of iOS?  Does manually adjusting brightness have any effect?

Comment: @Tetsujin Just added some more details to the OP, but I usually only use my phone when I'm in doors where the temperature is around 68F and it's fairly constant

Comment: @Allan Just added more details to the OP, but I'm using iphone 12 pro with latest iOS. The problem is when this happens, my screen gets dimmer, and I can't adjust the brightness any higher because it's still set to max

Comment: Please use the specific version of macOS as updates come quite often.

Comment: @Allan I am using iOS 13.1

Comment: That's why we ask for the specific version number.  iOS 16.3.1 (I believe) is the latest.

Comment: @Allan Oh I see. I thought 16.3 was just an umbrella term that covered all 16.3.x versions, but now I see maybe 16.3 means 16.3.0. Under Settings->About, I see "iOS 16.3 (20D47)".

Comment: You also said in your comment and edit you’re using 13.1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this abrupt luminosity changes are linked to your battery level and therefore the automated activation of low power mode. Low power mode slightly reduces your luminosity while in use. It normally activates automatically when your battery reaches 20% and deactivates when your battery is at 80%. If you are using your iPhone while charging it, it might be a reason.
There are 2 solutions to me:

1. Disable low power mode when it pops up.
2. Or, create an automation the "Shortcuts" saying that when low power mode is turned on, disable low power mode.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, it didn't happen with low power mode. I made sure of that as well. And the iphone was not charging during this.

Comment: Alright, have you checked nothing is "weird" in your luminosity settings?